# Want to preg_match numbers and period php

Tags: php, preg-match

I have this string `&OrigPlacedDate=41759.7128&` and I want to match the numbers **with** the period in the correct place. I have tried using

```
$string = '&OrigPlacedDate=41759.7128&'
$origPlacedDate = '/&OrigPlacedDate=[0-9^\.]*&/';
preg_match($origPlacedDate, $string, $origPlacedDateMatches);
$origPlacedDate = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $origPlacedDateMatches);
print_r($origPlacedDate);
```

but I am only getting the numbers.

```
Array ( [0] => 417597128 )
```

Ultimately I want to get an output of 41759.7128

Comment: What would be the desired output? I don't understand what *matching numbers with periods* means. What exactly are you looking to happen?

Comment: you couldn't get that array anyways - you have no capture groups (`()`), so the only stuff that'd go into $origPlacedDateMatches would be the entire matched string.

Comment: @MarcB I missed some of my code when asking the question, it has not been updated.

Comment: @Marcus I missed some of my code when asking the question, it has not been updated.

Comment: if you want `.`, then DON'T strip them out with the preg_replace... `[^0-9.]`

Comment: Maybe https://eval.in/557076? `&OrigPlacedDate=([\d.]+)&`. No need for `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were matching numbers, but you weren't including the `.` in the regular expression. Try this:

```
$string = '&OrigPlacedDate=41759.7128&';
$origPlacedDate = '/&OrigPlacedDate=[0-9^\.]*&/';
preg_match($origPlacedDate, $string, $origPlacedDateMatches);
$origPlacedDate = preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]/', '', $origPlacedDateMatches);
print_r($origPlacedDate);
```

---

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 41759.7128
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use a simpler approach by using a straightforward regular expression?

```
$string = '&OrigPlacedDate=41759.7128&';
$origPlacedDate = '/&OrigPlacedDate=([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)&/';
preg_match($origPlacedDate, $string, $origPlacedDateMatches);
echo $origPlacedDateMatches[1];
```

It outputs:

> 41759.7128